# Twilio API: Count messages number has received

Tags: php, twilio, twilio-php

Using the Twilio API in PHP how can I count the number of messages that a certain incoming number has received?

Comment: You have to ask your exact question in here .. also add some codes, errors and ..., We cannot get the problem with reading 1 line of explanation.

Comment: *"Using the Twilio API in PHP how can I count the number of messages that a certain incoming number has received?"* is too board for me ..!

Comment: Look, never mind `:-)`, btw, I enjoyed, you answer so fast `:-)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ricky from Twilio here.

You can access this information using the [Message List Resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/message#list). Here's an example using the [PHP helper library](https://www.twilio.com/docs/php/install):

```
  $sid = "{{ account_sid }}";                 
  $token = "{{ auth_token }}";                
  $client = new Services_Twilio($sid, $token);

  $count = 0;
  foreach ($client->account->sms_messages->getIterator(0, 50, array(
      'To' => '{{ phone_number }}',
  )) as $message) {
    $count++;
  }

  echo "Total Messages: " . $count;
```